# How to add class(active) when div show, when it's hide the remove class(active)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please tell me how i add class active when click, when not click then remove class (active).

Please check my code and tell me how to do that Thanks

I did this but nothing work.

```
   jQuery(function(){
     jQuery('#showall').click(function(){
           jQuery('#faq1').show();
    });
    jQuery('.showSingle').click(function(){
          jQuery('.targetDiv').hide().removeclass('active');


          jQuery('#faq'+jQuery(this).attr('target')).show().addClass( 'active' );

  });
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan becuase i made two buttons click to show one div content so i want to which click button it's be active and i change it background color from css thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p").click(function(e){
$("p").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Link 1</p>
<p>Link 2</p>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `show()` `hide()` methods.

Add to your CSS:

```
.yourTargetElementsSelector { display: none; }
.yourTargetElementsSelector.active { display: block; }
```

So, when you add the `.active` class, the element will be shown, othervise it will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks will you please did this on my script thanks :)

Comment: no, i will not. i can help - give an advice, but i will not do the work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML & Script

`<img src="path/img.png" id="IdForImage"/>`

`var addActive = document.getElementById("IdForImage");
addActive.classList.add('active'); 
addActive.classList.remove('active');`